# PRAW - Reply to new post with user account age

Tags: python, datetime, account, praw

Im new to Python.

I am creating a new bot, using PRAW and Python, that comments on new posts displaying their basic account information (Username, date account was created, karma count).

I am trying to have it display the years, months, and days the posters account has been active but so far only have it displaying years. Is there a better way I can get it to display this information, or maybe am I able to create it with what I have setup already? What I have so far is:

```
                author = post.author
                if author:
                    seconds_year = 60 * 60 * 24 * 365
                    now = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp()
                    difference = now - author.created_utc
                    years = difference // seconds_year
                    author_created = datetime.datetime.utcfromtimestamp(author.created_utc)
                    author_created = datetime.datetime.strftime(author_created, "%d %B %Y")
                    print("Commenting user history")
                    comment = COMMENT_TEMPLATE % (author.name, author_created, years, author.link_karma, author.comment_karma)
                    post.add_comment(comment)
            sql.commit()
```

Comment: unrelated: you could write `time.time()` instead of `datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp()`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`divmod()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) to find years, months, days:

```
DAY = 24 * 60 * 60 # seconds
MONTH = 30 * DAY
YEAR = 365.2524 * DAY # Gregorian year

years, seconds = divmod(difference, YEAR)
months, seconds = divmod(seconds, MONTH)
days, seconds = divmod(seconds, DAY)
```